# Encryption Reccomendation for Specific Borg Backup + Rclone Scenario

Tags: encryption, backup

I currently use **Borg** backup to make backup repositories of my system data on a local drive. I also use **Rclone** to transfer the repository to a Backblaze B2 cloud storage bucket.

Borg can create encrypted repositories. Rclone can encrypt the data it transfers to the Backblaze B2 bucket.

What are the pros and cons (from a security, usability, and resource perspective) of:

1. Encrypting the local repository with Borg. Not using Rclone to encrypt the repository while it is transferred to Backblaze.
2. Keeping an unencrypted local Borg repository. Using Rclone to encrypt the repository as it is transferred to Backblaze.
3. Both encrypting the local repository with Borg, and then using Rclone to "double encrypt???" the repository as it is transferred to Backblaze.

The local drive the Borg repository lives on can be considered secure.

Is there some security benefit to "encrypting it twice"? (once with Borg and again with Rclone) Are there downsides to encrypting it twice?

Comment: *"The local drive the Borg repository lives on can be considered secure."* - what exactly do you mean by that? That no malware is on it, that it is protecting against unauthorized used by others, that it has internal encryption which prevents data recovery even if the drive is broken, ...

Comment: *"Are there downsides to encrypting it twice?"* - Performance. And needing to remember two encryption keys.